# Align images with text baseline in <div>

Tags: html, css, image, text, vertical-alignment

I have a CGI script that creates a "navigation aid" consisting of arrow icons and text label like this:

[image: navigation aid rendering]

Obviously it would look much better if the text baseline would align with the bottom of the arrow icons.
The arrow icons were copied from GNOME 16x16 arrow actions a few years ago.

The HTML code is this:

```html
<div><a title="Erster Eintrag" href="#A0"><img alt="|<" src="/ig16a/go-first.png" class="toolbar"></a> <a href="#A0" title="Vorheriger Eintrag"><img src="/ig16a/go-previous.png" alt="<" class="toolbar"></a> <span class="navaid">2 von 29</span> <a href="#A2" title="Nächster Eintrag"><img src="/ig16a/go-next.png" alt=">" class="toolbar"></a> <a href="#A28" title="Letzter Eintrag"><img alt=">|" src="/ig16a/go-last.png" class="toolbar"></a></div>
```

The CSS used is:

```css
body {
    color: black;
}
.navaid, .toolbar {
    font-size: small;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #fffab7;
    margin-top: 1ex;
    margin-bottom: 1ex;
}
```

If someone wonders about the different classes:
The idea was to hide the arrow icons when printing the page...

In case someone needs the arrow icons (Sorry for the length!):

```````````````````````text
# tar czf - icons | uuencode icons.tar.gz
begin 644 icons.tar.gz
M'XL(`````````^R<"3B4:\/'QQ;'DK%ES1I)Q>Q#62=.=@F)&#3VI;$/LK<-
M1K84R5JV9`]%I`65?0\)T1`*=1A2?-1[ONM<N4Z]O(?W^VI^KO%<'N-Z'M=S
M___W;VZ/D90Z8N&E:F5A:>7J)@D&(4!(*3L,]I0;X!\$M`("!ONR7>';+0@$
M!P'`$`@"#`?!X8B5_6`("`0#"'K]DR?Q=WBXN5NXKIS*5ASK_R`0D*"%NYV3
ME1P8@01!H3!I&23]RC[,_^Z#(&3@8!C]?_L\R6P.7\(NM;G'6(TX$@[_^_R#
MUN0?C`0#!.&;>UI?^3/_KEBL^_>>]Z/O?_O+_3_AZ_5?,P?8G,(Z6?U3QUA7
M_T,1J]<?"4>2^W\K6-O_,N3^_X7XFO\O<=^T66!=_?\E_U`HB-S_6\)?K_^:
M60",\`(C_O-CK+__H7`8V?^WA&_[7P8$(O?_+\1?\_\E[ILP"ZR__V$@!(+<
M_UO!VNN_9A:P6"F#_VA%:%W]_^7U'QRR.O^3^W_S6=O_$'+__T*LS?^_XOX/
MS@/KZO^O^8=#H.3^WPK^_OJO71/"[O=PEG0^9;/>8_Q;_0^&KG0-$@Y"0E>N
M/Q*T\KJ#W/];P)K^1R+^VO\(:9BT-`Q"[O^?E;_/_X;COH8?Y!\,@D&^S3]D
M91H0W)),_N+]'W)$^S`3/<]JOIG45)6/KFR!JP^Z;2N?!3XL6ZQLJ-U0:OIT
M*_C26>)7ON9V5SGNKH>U=L=9N%H!<#B<I-TI!S>,A;.5)-;5)N&=+`\`0'%;
M35E)7SH\/*K9@4T76*=07&''EG"CE(6M#S:2[7#=MB--D"B65&[3O,1;Z3VY
M*'#/BRU"[@]AO+"/+O"5R@RK1'!PAW`O<;1J)E*?,&E_?YJ+V#@=+P7-DK#+
MKZHR^F1H:C"C&A4RR3/=JCQWS)@YDA$4!<?+WKUCG$#RQ=8KS]5&48@5B2HG
MF56ZEW,E9;>5=ST)VQVA99FP3!/WA*@\\F:\Y[5KNFO;Z;X>E6#N/+/?/N!E
MH5%,>BL_585WW"^52#<Q:T]L[TY^W#1SRN:*H^3N1@9K_J@K8D4EEK3")(VP
MFH117K'%A3X*D<R4%/HIW)PX^P>TB(G1-<5G>@"VGM/G/A4>O)(P2@1&O"`$
MJ-*8IX+"IKSW&:A792=*B+Q_J.Q)H3@^D8`+H@UD4X(&2>5V7259Y=<KE34O
M^4<4^%SS7'Q4T#=U^B9@OGKOH"=`EIK_P?-WYES+SMJ9EWGKU+$@YYNW``/+
MXDS!37.U@_D:P(.)EL/2A)T'^/NG'+%_'&WVRM*=%..-S)95"PD<V"YF(:U.
M2VT7>-=14?`B(?]Q4^K5CGC&%F1^GUIEL5IRFMV8R#AG4<C]JR=<G-E71X::
MBK9R'LH\^+\W-LEL/NOS/W?L1F:$#?@?&$E>_]T2R/[W:_-=_]M8W-?P0_]#
M@+_-/PR*)/O?5K!I_O?HJ_\EQC3;L^FR7[@/Q46[V/(D(.QX.1K-[7)NT^]X
M82DD?.J`\)C(/+M1^<0\D,C"7G.+G?UL'G4)[_(1.AJ&M-LAG6).$&B=2DS;
M^9`C`<Z<I"0W!?_1%V[IM^^UL2A)I^JW^N1&EP9U])\NT_%)MM%!4YI3R09\
ME.")M@GD:A$"[ZLVZ&RH-@8.D5Y9Z:C89H_G/N"KI@%V#CLW,XOMP\BCS:XJ
MQ`@T/YL[%M.)2\8=J=3--Y!G["W8)EE1&X<TW&&=H1UA];J]%G'RZ#[31&Z5
MD9)1V@^'*)($N/H04D2B9(/V#M<Y8K."LFY#-Y:)KRZV1@.](ZHL2>`2*T6I
MTTW1*<>[TJ:J`=C;^),TU`;'!QPAT=R%UE))]4)%XPM*,US5%1_&4H=O3(VZ
M7=>NZ']UR<EGZ,P2P8J/P)(A5J?UYI-[*FT\(++M_3.JP9E4-HRNI-EP7;Z<
M\5L_3QQI.M2HJZM*>3&Q0&>;%_.+VQ,EZAQ9_&]4D*&=\N."A$O:2,8@W\IC
M=MO]SE4]%-^6HC#TV2^:E8*621:FB/RDHQCPN%R7(,8$K;P/RLJMW=ZV5W`X
M`[^DBV)51'9-J-W5;ALRPWK<9BEJ?$=:'2AD'?PI69__V:X\;?TSP@;\#PJ!
MD/UO*R#[WZ_-=_UO8W%?PP_]#XGX-O_PE0W9_[:`?\?_MIW4.*P,6%[]2*G,
MC%G90^NNIJ5"V_4;'P,MF"DCX_F*[PU^];WTZ$8'-B6NVN3$_D9K7%2<!+MQ
MBSUJ3ZEIF+I*S:66DT*BJC5TY]J*!?G'E<2]GF3/G%EBX.^L$,>+<U3B,T/I
M2OUW3EZY^KR@IZ?I7=-%SKVU[Q#!4O<R20N?O<RWS3='#>N@>LU:\N+D,CDG
M:[P#!HZ+)H[SM^KUB_CXO7E*/!;Z>*CG5:Z,E@%1\Z3\6_'+3,)'VBV]S]%U
M+#6HT$,P2*G,=F)-SI5:EXYGC%R/?<7JJ;LS-)[>+^ZC-JV9L/$X5`GVD,\W
M3`0\NONH%[RWK]F;JT??+IBAN,X`]4[3],D$++(`/?`XXOR%H6OI3XO8]\SW
M"T*-GTJ$?K)]9:)M&*-VR^D.$!6XP#=EZ,28.'8&2`EH.2&QNU2:&W"@SH8D
MKNPM<U6AK>MEU15?DV*6:>"G;A_YPR4/(ML,.A!\N,\'><<+M/L7YSR3-"K3
M78.]:]TF6AX$Q9R1"\'5>YQ-Q=^JT#!L[;$>7!HV=+<J^8C2D%8Y=_1M*=#7
M>:B1]OAGVD&(%.LV`''QN9/$\:7WG8.ITFSS3RN>9=)"8P!B%?0<2O',Q(5"
M2D!*`RTSC;S"M:C22M09'W-TP?44I01>Q&]\5TH<!^_L0YNW=U$FE`*SP`+$
M9&J-?$[<V>O$W4'@A_=+C.17!P19!G\:UN=_IZR\W+?&_U9VD?UO"R#[WZ_-
M=_UO8W%?PP;6_Q!@LO]M"9N^_J>GY<"FRRZ'C;;-2C7=%4[-<3`X3P+/(!1*
M3Q\:GWZ:])'AI8+S$CY`T6O0V$5(7REKUN&57HR^@W%,9'R3IOQ+EU9/'LQN
M"JE[.$[2-;>IBBETI'*O4;:</VRO-FOPKK8&3Q,SNIFS(X=R;\C08]*+2/OT
M)"3E@2C9DIVD^66ZP?'8SD_/XF/*S@&EG.I,KUYDB"[86<:<`MK98+7_185>
MS7.@1S[XTW$L0@W=K5Z:0?.PM]_^9=%V!E9*P:`D@>L3=5GLG`5W[\+1`<NY
M5.\SCKE2`8IHST8)&9^0B[N45%I*=:F^/EXCWG'F;<7'O7TN#L9/.4.J!?G-
MD00+1@!?%O[1"<`!@G/IO5U-R0=-YT?@23T7'793ZL(4@8]!T*I9_>Q`[3):
MG3)/BA?=ZDOJU.=%J"J*YCF#J,O]"0.?Z6)?_<:81B<@'S!K-V8KFJPS9_['
MQ\9:KP,8!":D,XSSELDI"@M@RV+;'THOV]3S1./\S-3Y92VN%[YA/"\V15HD
MGAZV81YARAWYN,OZI?B%^M=MA9ZG;7A'X+DW2#JQV9.?$;?[#BHH'BN)#K\.
M^/"[-]/(:]A[=&C/A$E<65,`H./T_IJ`ZQF&JP.%K'P_)>OS/WL/IPW\16@C
M_@>#D_UO*R#[WZ_-=_UO8W%?PX_\;_5FOS7^!R;[WU;PGZS_=6_CH9>FX*=N
M[`8`*(]^];V:*#E--@NNNF52%<YI?\OEJR@6.L,;7)0GA5GU1-1VA]=RA"><
M^=U0C6"FL9N6M=_%??)&+9"]];$R&Y#572GEM?W>V_#]N,JVJ0J21[#^B>$Q
MK,][66]_;_G`Y7!GH-;Y;!,\6NPL>O2%+`U%[C4&JR`Z7>>YCD3WYENW7MR"
M<S":>(V`]\23^#P_'KZP^#:O=(<JJTJZO6`.L;`J7CR]Z"9*7;IX=@Z=AU8$
M<V=('EJ$N?C8>DV>';`OQF=Q;].O)+PE;(_18V2:4R7\I@U/9L[B_=#LS\8W
M&SXPO7#/,&+AXG&%_%/L"I)Y\0Y19Z/:&5Z_N^@9=E5*),=P\,I!V_%,8NFL
M]K[7P@S/J@)!03IO5-J73OKK1H@?+!-/K62-\L%UFMAZ>V":AV\+E1D&H[,>
M[L;)[!$MF]@-Y+99<A0[87G>112Q:)Z7-W=GN>T/N)84@:\(.':.OM?4R5PQ
M!:V8I7A9!C-ULI@TD4`!X/.M,,X)HJ,,C>79MX/%O*'_4SA@)*P=7?V)OKHX
MF5=.GB[75K%(-;)2>]\],WM?C)S<:/(=E<*/J3GM<H(DCQ,RH_AWMLXR;R,K
M)9VWB\]<NLNA-?GP,?6"WO3P;$=>+'V0OO'G(NX%],TNKEO1=$V!-Y\"PYUX
M3[1ZL=Y#Y#7TFV+C!LT3S9^(W>Y%R_#E4MS-KWMG6RR2I'IL>,:2KT,VYYYO
MW*ERE!P&`XWNS3[GY-DG<Z'X7(9>/-9$@A;3?*C7#-M2;1GW3$64L4G[,J/+
MKL]$[:%DN7!G(2[&D$:)^P`>$F57;#[:>G6<DO5S<UB?_SF[6GG:83W<UC<I
MK-O_("`(C/S_'UL"V?]^;;[K?QN+^QI^Y']@$.3;_,-!<++_;06;MO[7\>?Z
M7Y]]QQ%VTX-J\9KP1,L,^+!FG78&^PUV/Z#OD6DJGFD&Y0"1@)9Y*O_`9,$1
M)0EU#H[6PRI*(%0ZIL_E`"8FDN'IG&A[WZX/@T$U,@4DM,-;OR8**&9'><()
MYI6'NI%)-<$J+F(_0(<";R5SU"552_D/93TI.;[EV?9]PT>C]M">MS/$C_7$
MUO1>/XW#-FFD13:YJC5D3IZWZ\:/U;CF%+I@,%H[1%GR/>73Z]#'NX(]4>9Q
MG@EX-*G<\&!.3C=Q^T7*)T5G:U$<E%IO7BW,+8IKMV5<XLP_8SOZT?BP0XF'
MRU1$!`RCC"84<NH\S1NC%WL8;='+`>A+[#IYJ/O*F$T``2;0:X>+H0IZ@,=P
M&_&SF]2%`EX,]//R+;\4<,Z5>,",\O*G4X@3?,8B3">L;.&+\O?<-B'HTSY1
M:I">0?<YB-G*?_LL#3?EZT-/<$&!S`(*AXUJ&\/*6JA:*YJ*7AZ!&T0K4YC=
M]]5Y*+W'QUD8\-:DVN.6@'E5R:+#_0`OD&H1@454;5L*T^![&GW3.IY$-^?:
MIZPLE;G=G;%#T_CX5O>=#OJ#:?-2=RYZ/&DHN_"H%6FM'^IJS3JR2\2ZBFKP
M=0#+R"YY`%N@X>4/S-Q=I/T//\9N7QTY9"/[&5B?_YW$NKMCG=8['6Q@_0^!
M)/O?ED#VOU^;[_K?QN*^AA_Y'P@)^];_P#"R_VT)F^9_37_Z7[T]NQ*[7*=!
M:],AL=K#RL4%(2&6(O1YKWX'*CGVTY6[C/96?J8M-1L\3&V2_J`D03$8GY(C
MK6<A=G%G-/<D]^D,@4X/4W>DIO4!:KF$F^4=,J27>F5<+!;LE]_.4<3%45/<
MV26WFXLI-#2,&)8Y$<P[>=P9X[;W6+SU\)4<ZI3X:I(UIP47!H1W66YB?4X-
MOZ#+T0`+$I<R9A,RX,$D)HFE?-"*@AN47_5+4[R<*3*2\PQ6VR@IM*_/CV;0
M;X_8'2']'I0N*@VBF<@B'-9VJ-Y3XQTG@)F;Y8'/^Z;$A'A_O\6N<*,FIL?Q
M0>:1YB`"RWD6R:Z,PCL@*H#M9UG]\,I2YK2*-K?MC(#(!.PU<37997'5N#@4
M5_HY&F^:Q)?`(9!*W]18+;J"(<WCC0QMG>R1;)\]KY?FI);%$Q5P.Q:X1OS,
M*D$7!,?:3_DI`%KEWLCD1M?]WECHB+O,L+1`O%EB<M",S3^3-@9ZP^6LP.RQ
M?,$`7GB4`>&]U:'I?`>'^K`,NZ*!?L#L[\7,:;1M;IZU9A:H%*`1F'K`J-PS
MO<N^=!D8M5]N5*\36C01,9`$PF0>\MG.!IB>7+@>(!;P?)XN95[S]5#`-"?S
MO=X]L:)];:MCAFQ^/P_K\S]K.U>W]=\1M`'_@T/([_^U)9#][]?FN_ZWL;BO
MX8?K?^`U^?_R_M]D_]M\-LW_>K_ZG]^_[O^;PD"LHS43J`EFV=RYQJ'BJG:<
MP8*O4#:Z+0)#9G$!+3,"[J,/*UMJ!M/87838E2(E]<5=8)W'G""FFM66$&AW
MC;+CZ",&9GY2TNEW<E/]]0>8NRD!]*Q[*R["4<\8V_TI!^,GCBL=J.6F.N'G
M+D`H%-^I&9V<1W&<MOK#*TBS3*[$6>%DY'BLP90M%^?0_[1S[]]0IW$`Q[\V
M8T;#&'+-;18QLDJA8D)R*9>2$L:E4J-5F'&_M2$-@U5)R=;$6(U:XY(:I,08
M<PQ;KDGCTC0N76A"F]6@6KO.[F_.J9-S<G:WY_4'?'_Z/.>\SW.>SS<,+]WU
MB'R>ZK'VEJ8`CW^HO$Q!EF!NY%RC3X^IK.[`5_<0]5TWG_#*"C)!'>=4=(4X
MKF@)U:\B^M"LNLSYF;7[+8_ZPT3C92'E"?SUD*M1P_W2:#W<0!))<"<V^'!4
M%9>ECI)M%&_7Y$PV'7A%*$1*FVI;^ZQOXP7NE::)SJ`I$<[3`E6;(7_$U.X4
MS'B4R'Z576?$WL;H!,3J'\PQ&1528K*#;,J9LG#_.E\S7LG-#VQTG)T=,VKU
MV1#G)IT,8W'HM6)^?PV_EI=[FQE77!9N%W97,",/L_Z)E]K<<D+HB<-X_?$`
MIRPUNT^YB7PD;,46T\A[M\^-F#\J\^MS@ENA!,X-OR03!KBQQ[)P:7NR-%(O
MS!Z?,(!<R<.V^:>4J)@"J>;($AK&2Z+<U[9^)"'!U)1380#%UYS.QC.L]#`E
M6SL.;8F<GQ_0@O]MG]=_!%(T<8G>_X'^6Q*@_[YN'^V_Q1WW!3YY_[=AP?XO
M>/^W1+Y8_S7_LP]\ED5<88WFLGQIAFIFB/ZP75E:/LD!F8DF:>*I*4DV)D\E
M"^Z*P3RN#L<@\J![/I+^:%AZX7;7?/R+)`?;/QZ;60KZ1-]3AMJPZZ*O'BCL
M=F0:LTC/5>UMIVE7=DA$<):+G4>^$39LJ"V"H*"Q1NW7<G#*-WHP*(95:9%^
M<&H"!6%<R18OY-D'Q*V4AP;Y=O([[DV*791SHFU^-IJHDZU-)UW&RE_,1:9V
M;S(+_M8Q'=<1P?&"OR:J80/5'(L,C+>%)CD6EOSJ-_(RQ10U`<4TI")F)V]1
MF947/63&^46AI>+[4T;@LG2I01F=E4Q>!\.#K<+Q$WD\#CV=D!B`[WFN`H=N
M3,5UB4[*C/$GV-@,#"54-ZMJ<-9&BD#FT/0<FLPLQ3H9Y:U,`PUTIWV[D)30
MKW33O;N^5Q-IY$$[P1,6M['/4A4T3PE[_*,C.8SUW+H*X@;26D-#]YT6:<OU
M,NCT-NM;\`(%/^J[G!V$<\).Z6));M\D,GRRU)WY]+92R.5Q6*H&LC_(A3BX
M=HM$)[N'9W\E?OC]8_7$D:+RUO;8P!88(?,=9"D6HQ\T>8@H!Z%=!VNG7K5.
M'9FS)0MTXB3#%>6TQ^:G!=3>_\WG]5^0WV+N`Q;3?\9@_V-)@/[[NGVT_Q9W
MW!?X=/^9+.@_([#_NR2^6/]Q_^Z_Y"P7)]7Y_\'TMAPEZR@&_B:SJM5SEU<`
MVQU;@4U.DK^FQV8*ZB?CEVT;*<J)1_Q,:=AZ/3F/@35,KZQ2[Y3(_BYM76!5
M)_^X1:K?1GXW_(G?0"Q-T')?2EM+QV%[97ZPT#>=AU))&W6J52!=>((L\LPR
MPXEF[2$A*YNZT6P.2W_I&'@'E:C4KO$VX[3B-;,7^\ENR72--?2C4'/42MV-
M,<IRCHWL-<1+PZI4%H_L=JZO"G40@GI'<URJ>W-AG@0?";4:PX?4-2GPV4WM
MRH53$U8LR2)=G!@"@=7,2]2:&1E^7UJM_,J`H,O5_/UZ&:F4'(^&3\<GVG<M
MJZ^OAWP*\<<^#%>&D/+KN>-*D][]YJA-(IN8)RJ[Z\2A@?%<-;5KZ9JX&HW$
MO&GI)+2V3>T-2'97^-Q@3[#?=!1J'S-M++=V#[H5FE:#=?"Z6R'U(963%G&;
M#T=0U?2F)$;Y-Y$=!L'>!EL9/8B9M^6R,]8]?WW^BGLQY=D;5_5\_6!OU3EU
M>G!QM@DS<SEEV\X!-\9>M`6O:LJ@:**/-N+&@&/B+BG6299+%$@&>[]S>$YY
MYI*CJN58\J#EH&7KCX]@EA0!]T&`1?_\K(#Z`P``````````````````````
5````````````^/?X$XK8@%``H```
`
end
```````````````````````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top | middle | bottom;` in your CSS to align vertically.

Also ensure you use `display: inline-block;` in your CSS to align to the top / bottom of your images correctly.

Note: You can also use `display: inline-flex | inline-grid;`. See [MDN for details of `display` options.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```css
body {
  color: black;
}

.navaid,
.toolbar {
  font-size: small;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #fffab7;
  margin-top: 1ex;
  margin-bottom: 1ex;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-top .navaid,
.nav-top .toolbar {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-middle .navaid,
.nav-middle .toolbar {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-bottom .navaid,
.nav-bottom .toolbar {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-grid;
}
```

```html
<p>Align Top</p>
<div class="nav nav-top">
  <a title="Erster Eintrag" href="#A0">
    <img alt="|<" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Gnome-go-first.svg/48px-Gnome-go-first.svg.png" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
  <a href="#A0" title="Vorheriger Eintrag">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/Gnome-go-previous.svg/48px-Gnome-go-previous.svg.png" alt="<" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
  <span class="navaid">2 von 29</span>
  <a href="#A2" title="Nächster Eintrag">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Gnome-go-next.svg/48px-Gnome-go-next.svg.png" alt=">" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
  <a href="#A28" title="Letzter Eintrag">
    <img alt=">|" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Gnome-go-last.svg/48px-Gnome-go-last.svg.png" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
</div>
<p>Align Middle</p>
<div class="nav nav-middle">
  <a title="Erster Eintrag" href="#A0">
    <img alt="|<" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Gnome-go-first.svg/48px-Gnome-go-first.svg.png" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
  <a href="#A0" title="Vorheriger Eintrag">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/Gnome-go-previous.svg/48px-Gnome-go-previous.svg.png" alt="<" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
  <span class="navaid">2 von 29</span>
  <a href="#A2" title="Nächster Eintrag">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Gnome-go-next.svg/48px-Gnome-go-next.svg.png" alt=">" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
  <a href="#A28" title="Letzter Eintrag">
    <img alt=">|" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Gnome-go-last.svg/48px-Gnome-go-last.svg.png" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
</div>
<p>Align Bottom</p>
<div class="nav nav-bottom">
  <a title="Erster Eintrag" href="#A0">
    <img alt="|<" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Gnome-go-first.svg/48px-Gnome-go-first.svg.png" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
  <a href="#A0" title="Vorheriger Eintrag">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/Gnome-go-previous.svg/48px-Gnome-go-previous.svg.png" alt="<" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
  <span class="navaid">2 von 29</span>
  <a href="#A2" title="Nächster Eintrag">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Gnome-go-next.svg/48px-Gnome-go-next.svg.png" alt=">" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
  <a href="#A28" title="Letzter Eintrag">
    <img alt=">|" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Gnome-go-last.svg/48px-Gnome-go-last.svg.png" class="toolbar" />
  </a>
</div>
<p>Some text</p>
```

*Remove side note concerning frameworks*

Comment: Good answer just using a framework for such a small issue is way over the top. It's no heavy lifting and even a simple flexbox would solve it more or less by default.

Comment: Correct. However, as a non-css expert (and I would dare to say this question originates from someone similarly inclined), using bootstrap as a starting point will generally mean that you have readily available documentation for common cross-browser compatible styled components without a great deal of cognitive load. But yes, here, a single line of CSS is enough.

Comment: _using bootstrap as a starting point will generally mean that you have readily available documentation for common cross-browser compatible styled components without a great deal of cognitive load_ That is no reason to use a framework

Comment: MDN is a good API for Web languages such as CSS and is easier to read than the original W3C and WHATWG specifications. IMHO you should not start learning Frameworks without fundamental knowledge of vanilla coding. If you already know how to code without frameworks you have it way easier to understand how a framework works and what it could do. Going the other way you will have it way harder to progress once the limitations of a framework appear. At that point, you have no idea what is going wrong and why it is going wrong.

Comment: That's exactly the reason to use a framework. To make it faster to develop (less steep learning curve if you're not aesthetically minded), less bugs (cross-browser compatible style), useful helper methods (documented and tuned utilities for common scenarios), out-of-the-box styled components and theming (no need to reinvent). THAT BEING SAID, once you know the rules, you can break them. Frameworks are a means to an end and a good place to start, but you certainly wouldn't want to rely on them for a large production systems (performance and homogenity). Anyway, I don't use frameworks.

Comment: @dangarfield i don't mean to attack you or anything like that, but using a framework without knowing the language (be it css, javascript or whatever) is kinda counterproductive if you can't debug it **when** you run in to problems.
:)

Comment: Yep yep yep! Vanilla CSS and vanilla JS all the way : )

Comment: The solution looks better than the original (question), but the original intention was to align the *baseline* on the text with the bottom of the images.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I've updated the description but left the demo the same. Use `vertical-align: bottom;` but also include `display: inline-block;` also.

Comment: Updated with examples of top / middle / bottom align.

Comment: The "bottom" variant has a negative side-effect on another navigation element not shown in the question; however when I use `display: inline-block` instead it looks OK (while not understanding all the details; I just tried different settings until it looked OK).

Answer (score -2):

maybe try adding this to your CSS:

```
.toolbar{
  margin-bottom: 0;  
}
```